# When calling a function from a module can you say what is returned? (Python)

Tags: python

It may sound a bit noobish but say i call a function from the module psutils, is there a way to say which value i want back

for example:

```
    psutil.swap_memory()
```

returns

```
    swap(total=A, used=B, free=C, percent=D, sin=0, sout=0)
```

is there a way to make it only return B and C?

Comment: i don't think so, whats wrong with just accessing the data you  need?
`swap = psutil.swap_memory(); swap.free; swap.used`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways, the most obvious being:

```
info = psutil.swap_memory()
used, free = info.used, info.free
```

The returned object is actually a tuple-like object, so you could also slice it and then unpack it:

```
used, free = psutil.swap_memory()[1:3]
```

There's also the more convoluted approach, which has the advantage of ignoring order:

```
from operator import attgetter

used, free = attrgetter('used', 'free')(psutil.swap_memory())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dm03514's posting, I suggest you use a customized wrapper for swap_memory():

```
def my_swap_memory():
    _, used, free, _, _, _ = psutil.swap_memory()
    return swap(B=used, C=free)
```

and then call it like

```
returndata = my_swap_memory()
```